# Why can only primitive data types be copied through a constructor parameter in a class

Tags: java

For instance, in this class.

```
class Example {
    public ImageView imageView;

    public Example(ImageView imageView) {
        // say imageView is initialized
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }
}
```

The `imageView` only points to the `imageView` that is passed in the constructor as a parameter and its not the same as below.

```
class Example {
    public int i;

    public Example(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

The above code copies the value passed as `i` in the constructor to the `i` of the object that called the constructor.

But even String gets copied even thought it's a class and not a primitive data type.

```
class Example {
    public String s;

    public Example(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** follow up question - so how can i make a copy of `imageView` which is the exact duplicate of the `imageView` passed in constructor such that changes to one `imageView` doesn't affect the other?

Comment: is java pass by value or pass by reference - your answer

Comment: The String is not copied. The *reference* to the String is copied. Same for ImageView. Java passes everything by value, including references to objects.

Comment: @Scary java is pass by value of reference isn't it? But how is that the answer?

Comment: Why do you think the String is being copied?

Comment: @JB ok and what about the int i, is that being copied or is it the reference for that too?

Comment: An int is not an object. So i is not a reference. It's a primitive value. Primitive values, like references, are passed by value. So yes, a copy of the int is passed.

Comment: @JB ok so in a "real" sense only primitive data can be "actually" copied and nothing else right? everything else is just the reference to the objects location.

Comment: If "in the real sense" means "in an imaginary world where references don't exist", and if "nothing else" means "and also references", then yes.

Comment: There is no generic way in java to copy an object.

Comment: thank-you guys i just realized i know nothing about java. But in my defense in real world when you have a paper with content on it and you make a photo-copy of it,you could do anything to the said copy of the paper without affecting anything on the original paper. So that's what a non-programmer would call a real copy. But anyways, thank-you again :)

Comment: @cpp does it exist in c++?

Comment: Yes i think so but i’m not 100% sure. In some languages when you write a = b you are actually copying the bytes of b into a, so subsequent changes to a do not affect b and vice versa. In java that’s not the case. a = b means they now refer to the exact same instance, so you only have one object. With strings, the distinction is largely irrelevent as you can’t modify a string anyway.

Answer (score 1):

@panarama, you can achieve it by doing following steps...

First implements the `Cloneable` interface in class you want to create duplicate object of (in our case, `ImageView`).

Then in `ImageView` class, override clone() method like following...

```
@Override
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
}
```

So now your updated ImageView class would look like:

```
public class ImageView implements Cloneable {

    ...

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

And finally, you can clone the object which passed into constructor of `Example` class and assign it to the `imageView` object of `Example` class like...

```
public Example(ImageView imageView){
    // say imageView is initialized
    this.imageView = (ImageView) imageView.clone();
}
```

After that, changes done to one imageView will not affect the other.

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet **imageView**  is a object of type **ImageView** which will be loaded into memory at the time of class loading time as the constructor get called this object will point out to the address of the constructor's parameter but primitive values aren't treated similar to class or object for that matter.

In your last snippet, Strings are stored into literal pool in Java so if already exist it won't create new Object just Point to the new value.

Answer (score -1):

> A Java String contains an immutable sequence of Unicode characters. Unlike C/C++, where string is simply an array of char, A Java String is an object of the class java.lang. Java String is, however, special. Unlike an ordinary class:
>
> String is associated with string literal in the form of double-quoted texts such as "Hello, world!". You can assign a string literal directly into a String variable, instead of calling the constructor to create a String instance.

Comment: There is nothing special about Strings regarding how they're passed as arguments, which is what the question is about.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant and just copied and pasted from the internet.